# Expanding child UL when clicked not working in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm new to JS and having an issue toggle `show` / `hide` for a hidden `ul` menu.

Source:

```
<ul class="main-menu">
    <li class="static-content" data-leaf="true" id="contact">
        <a href="contactUs.html">Contact Us</a>
    </li>

    <li class="" data-leaf="false" id="rules">
        <a href="">Sports Betting Rules</a>

        <ul class="submenu" id="submenu-rules" style="display: none;">
            <li class="static-content wager-types" data-leaf="true" id=
            "types">
                <a href="wagerTypes.html">Wager Types</a>
            </li>

            <li class="static-content" data-leaf="true" id="odds">
                <a href="oddsAndLines.html">Odds &amp; Lines</a>
            </li>

            <li class="static-content rules-policies" data-leaf="true" id=
            "policies">
                <a href="rulesAndPolicies.html">Rules &amp; Policies</a>
            </li>

            <li class="static-content" data-leaf="true" id="bonuses">
                <a href="sportsBonuses.html">Sports Bonuses</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="" data-leaf="false" id="conditions">
        <a href="">Terms &amp; Conditions</a>

        <ul class="submenu" id="submenu-conditions" style="display: none;">
            <li class="static-content" data-leaf="true" id=
            "termsOfService">
                <a href="termsOfService.html">Terms of Service</a>
            </li>

            <li class="static-content" data-leaf="true" id="privacy">
                <a href="privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="static-content" data-leaf="true" id="view">
        <a href="view.html">View in: Mobile | Full Site</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
// Expanding JS for sub-menus
    $('.submenu').hide();
    $(".li a").click(function (e) {
        if ($(this).parent().data("leaf") == 'false') {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).siblings('ul').toggle();
        }

        return false;
    });
```

When I click the link that has the parent `li data-leaf` of false I need it to `toggle` / `show` the child `ul` but think I'm doing something wrong.

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: please use [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/?html,css,output) next time to create a test page

Comment: Will do mate, thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 0):

you can target the selector using the data attribute: `$('li[data-leaf="false"]>a')`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.submenu').hide();
    $('li[data-leaf="false"]>a').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
     console.log('hey hey');
        $(this).closest('li').find('ul').toggle();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><ul class="main-menu">
    <li class="static-content" data-leaf="true" id="contact">
        <a href="contactUs.html">Contact Us</a>
    </li>

    <li class="" data-leaf="false" id="rules">
        <a href="">Sports Betting Rules</a>

        <ul class="submenu" id="submenu-rules" style="display: none;">
            <li class="static-content wager-types" data-leaf="true" id=
            "types">
                <a href="wagerTypes.html">Wager Types</a>
            </li>

            <li class="static-content" data-leaf="true" id="odds">
                <a href="oddsAndLines.html">Odds &amp; Lines</a>
            </li>

            <li class="static-content rules-policies" data-leaf="true" id=
            "policies">
                <a href="rulesAndPolicies.html">Rules &amp; Policies</a>
            </li>

            <li class="static-content" data-leaf="true" id="bonuses">
                <a href="sportsBonuses.html">Sports Bonuses</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="" data-leaf="false" id="conditions">
        <a href="">Terms &amp; Conditions</a>

        <ul class="submenu" id="submenu-conditions" style="display: none;">
            <li class="static-content" data-leaf="true" id=
            "termsOfService">
                <a href="termsOfService.html">Terms of Service</a>
            </li>

            <li class="static-content" data-leaf="true" id="privacy">
                <a href="privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="static-content" data-leaf="true" id="view">
        <a href="view.html">View in: Mobile | Full Site</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

your code has 2 issues.

1.`.li` is not a class it is html element so it should be `$("li>a").click(function (e) {`
2. the value `false` is boolean not string so use this  `if ($(this).parent().data("leaf") == false) {`

[Your code working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/umn1b5z8/)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove .(dot) before li in your js, it working great!

```
// Expanding JS for sub-menus
    $('.submenu').hide();
    $("li a").click(function (e) {
        if ($(this).parent().data("leaf") == 'false') {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).siblings('ul').toggle();
        }

        return false;
    });
```